# Why Angular UI-Grid is not working with angular updated version 1.6.5?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid, angularjs-1.6

I am facing a problem which is, my Angular `ui-grid` is failed to load data in it's grid when I am using updated version of `angular JS`. It's working fine with angular lower version of 1.5.0 however, not working with `1.6.5`.

Additionally, it's not showing any error regarding the grid too. According to the Ui-grid [documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/101_intro) I can see that they have only used angular `1.5.0`, but what about the latest version like 1.6.+

I don't prefer using the older version of angualr js. And I am using the latest version of `ui-grid(4.0.11, latest)` so do the `Angular` too.

Could you suggest anything regarding this or, any alternative grid having same facilities?

Link using  [1.6.5](http://plnkr.co/edit/EnDumr3DHIkSxec3VSDg)

Link using  [1.5.0](http://plnkr.co/edit/6MzvV24SGLjBqrpZFnp1?p=preview)

Comment: 1.6 has the new promise API (https://toddmotto.com/angular-1-6-is-here#http-success-and-error) so probably that's the problem. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/search?p=8&q=success&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93

Comment: I have changed the `then-success-failure` maintaining the rule of `1.6.5` instead of previous versions `get-success-failure` from `1.5.0` and in response the data is getting from the API as well. But it's generating the grid only with no content in it and with no error in console.  Just an empty grid.

Comment: dont't sure that problem with this, even on main page on Github, said that `ui-grid` support Angular 1.6

Comment: @lazycoder can you please provide [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to illustrate your issue?

Comment: I have updated the my question with live code. Please check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second example, use this for your `$http` method:

```
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(resp) {
      $scope.gridOptions.totalItems = 100;
      var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;
      $scope.gridOptions.data = resp.data.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
    });
```

The minimal change is just to change your 1.6.5 to this. The response object contains headers, so you need the `data` property from it.

```
$scope.gridOptions.data = response.data.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
```

Comment: It's working!!. Pretty cool solution. But in `1.6.5` we need to use `response.data` as well for every `$http.get()`, why is that? it was not as before.

Comment: George's answer here says it perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35331339/4614870